# Apple Mail: How to semi-automatically forward an email with default text and recipients

Tags: mail.app, email, ms-office

i converted recently from windows, and i do a lot of email dispatching, which i did in outlook with quick steps. 
I could mark an email, hit a button for team A, and a fowarded email was composed with team a as recipients and some text in the email. Same was possible for emails for team B and so on.

Does anybody know, how this can be done in Apple Mail (or Mac Outlook, I'm not picky)?
(mbp, high sierra)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would look into using [Automator](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/automator/welcome/mac). For example, you could create a Service that is accessible from the Application menu (e.g. Mail > Services) that does what you want.

Speaking of Services, there's actually already one available for Mail that does *part* of what you want. More specifically:

1. In Mail, select an email
2. Then go to Mail > Services > New Email With Selection
3. A new email window opens with the contents of the email you selected already in the body of the message (however, there is no subject line and the message is not formatted as though you're forwarding it)

Also, with regards to Team A and Team B, if you haven't already you can create a Group in the Contacts app for each of your teams. That way you can forward the email to the group.

You could look at using [AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html), but in this case Automator is probably the best/easiest option. There are many online resources that can help you get started. Below are three of them:

- [Automator Help](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/automator/welcome/mac)
- [MacOSXAutomation.com](https://www.macosxautomation.com/automator/)
- [Automator World](http://automatorworld.com)

Finally, feel free to come back here and ask questions if/when you get stuck.

Comment: Hi there, I was just wondering how you went with this? Did you get things sorted in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using now since a while AppleScript via script editor, if anyone is interested:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Mail"
        set frontmost to true
        keystroke "f" using {command down, shift down}
        delay 1
        keystroke "a@comp.com, b@comp.com"
        keystroke tab & tab & tab
        keystroke "Hallo, " & return & return & "FYI" & return & return & return & "Thanks," & return & "Max" & return
    end tell
end tell
```

If you have any improvements, I'm glad to hear.